# How do I pull from an API with AJAX format?

Tags: javascript, api

How do I pull from API's in AJAX format such as these:

http://live.nhle.com/GameData/RegularSeasonScoreboardv3.jsonp
http://live.nhle.com/GameData/RegularSeasonScoreboardv3.jsonp

I am an amateur programmer so anything in Javascript would be helpful

Comment: [Use jQuery's AJAX method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). There are also plenty of tutorials out there.

Comment: To be fair, there are plenty of other frameworks besides jQuery that offer AJAX abstraction. You could also use the core JavaScript AJAX API (which doesn't require a JS framework), but it's been abstracted in all of these frameworks for a reason (i.e. it can be difficult to work with). You should at least start learning with the [MDN documentation on AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX).

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner so what would be the simplest way of extracting the data in these API's? Would it be these methods you told me?

Comment: @ajp15243, fair points, but the OP is self-claimed amateur and I was trying to make it easy.

Comment: Yea so @Andy would your method be the simplest to learn how to extract this data?

Comment: @Andy Understandable, and it's one of the fastest ways to get something up and working, but amateurs will only become better by understanding the foundations, just as all the current experts have done before.

Comment: @user3479400 jQuery is generally good for fast development on sites that aren't JS-heavy, so at least for now it's probably your best bet for getting something working without much effort.

Comment: @ajp15243 Since I am an amateur, I'm just a bit confused on what I have to do to pull this data. I am supposed to use jQuery? If so, how?

Comment: @user3479400 "supposed to" is a bit to strong. You aren't required to use jQuery. It's a library that, among many other things, makes using the AJAX functionality provided by browsers a bit easier to work with. Icarus' answer provides a good example on how to use it. You'll need to include the jQuery JavaScript script file in your page before you can use jQuery in your own JavaScript code. See jQuery's [How jQuery Works page](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to extract this data is to use jQuery to make a cross domain ajax request. Basically, the idea is this:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'jsonp', //data in jsonp
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: 'http://live.nhle.com/GameData/RegularSeasonScoreboardv3.jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: 'loadScoreboard', 
    success: function (data) {
       alert(data.games.length + ' games loaded');
    }
});
```

You'll notice that the jsonpCallback is set to loadScoreboard because that's what the jsonp data looks like.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3mQh7/1/) with a full working sample.

Fire up Developer tools in Google Chrome (hit F12 in your keyboard) and click on the `console` tab to see the full response.

Update: Here's another fiddle with better output results: http://jsfiddle.net/3mQh7/6/

Now let me explain in more detail:

1. The above code uses jQuery, which is just a Javascript library that you can include in your page.
2. jQuery itself has a bunch of utility functions that make it easy(er) to make an Ajax request (which is what you need in this case). So the line that says `$.ajax(...` is just me calling the jQuery function to make ajax requests.
3. Since this is an Ajax request to another third-party website, you need to initiate what's called a Cross Domain Resource Sharing ([CORS](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing&ei=h3k5U7yJHa3jsASIpoHoCw&usg=AFQjCNE_31Mb5cZfSHHiHh6_hzNPhL3-7A&bvm=bv.63808443,d.cWc)) Ajax request. In order to do this, you need to specify some special parameters in your function call. For example, you need to specify that the data type that you expect to receive back is of type [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) (essentially, you are asking to receive data in Javascript Object Notation format - JSON)
4. Finally, the data returned by the website you linked defines a callback function called `loadScoreboard` - you can see this by simply going to the link and analyzing the output. As a result, when you make the ajax request, you must name the callback function the same as the one presented in the output from the site. If you don't, jQuery automatically creates one for you with a unique identifier, but since it doesn't match the name that's imposed by the website (namely `loadScoreboard`), you would get errors. That's why you need to define the parameter jsonCallback='loadScoreboard'.

So the whole thing is simply making an XHTML HTTP GET Request to get a resource on a third party website that returns data in JSON format. When the data is returned, a function called `loadScoreboard` is expected to be called immediately with the data itself passed in as parameter to this function.

If you look at my second fiddle you'll see a more elaborate example, which iterates through the results and creates a table.

Comment: Sorry, since I am an amateur I'm not quite sure what this is doing and what this script acts as.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this alerts me the number of games played, is this correct? If so how do I make it alert me the scores?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this alerts me the number of games played, is this correct? If so how do I make it alert me the scores?????